# An r-length permuter in c++

Tags: c++, combinatorics

In relation to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392431/how-to-create-a-permutation-in-c-using-stl-for-number-of-places-lower-than-the), I myself came up with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394238/11930602). I would like constructive criticism and tips to improve it to make it efficient like the other answers that have been posted.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> job_list;
    std::set<std::vector<int>> permutations;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        int job;
        std::cin >> job;
        job_list.push_back(job);
    }
    std::sort(job_list.begin(), job_list.end());
    std::vector<int> original_permutation = job_list;
    do {
        std::next_permutation(job_list.begin(), job_list.end());
        permutations.insert(std::vector<int>(job_list.begin(), job_list.begin() + 3));
    } while (job_list != original_permutation);

    for (auto& permutation : permutations) {
        for (auto& pair : permutation) {
            std::cout << pair << " ";
        }
        std::endl(std::cout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the code is nice and readable.  Here's some small suggestions:

- This:

  ```
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      int job;
      std::cin >> job;
      job_list.push_back(job);
  }
  ```

  can be simplified (?) to

  ```
  std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, 7, std::back_inserter(job));
  ```
- Introduce variables when you use them.  For example, the declaration of `permutations` may be moved after reading and sorting the numbers.
- Marking `original_permutation` as `const` indicates that it is used for comparison only.
- Use `emplace`:

  ```
  permutations.emplace(job_list.begin(), job_list.begin() + 3);
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  permutations.insert(std::vector<int>(job_list.begin(), job_list.begin() + 3));
  ```
- `const auto&` in the `for` loops.  Also, `std::cout << '\n'` instead of `std::endl(std::cout)`.
- Consider extracting the functionality into a function and changing magic numbers to arguments.

Of course, there are more efficient ways to do this.  Your code generates
$$ 7! = 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 5040 $$
permutations, but only end up with
$$ 7^{\underline{3}} = 7 \times 6 \times 5 = 210 $$
results, and let `std::set` discard the remaining \$5040 - 210 = 4830\$ permutations.  You can modify your code so that it only stores one in \$4! = 24\$ permutations, but the other answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61392431) provide better algorithms.